# jQuery Radio button click event not working on iOS Safari only

Tags: jquery, ios

I have a Radio button where clicking it shows or hides some divs. It works fine everywhere except Safari on iOS. Nothing happens at all on there.
Here is the HTML:

I found a lot of other questions on here that lead to clicks on other elements not working in iOS Safari, so I tried the solutions like this one https://gravitydept.com/blog/js-click-event-bubbling-on-ios but not having any luck with that.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="PaymentTypeRadio" value="onetime"> One Time Payment<br>
<input type="radio" name="PaymentTypeRadio" value="preauth"> Pre-Authorized Payments Sign-up<br>
...
<div class="form-group" id="PreauthDiv" style="display: none">
...
</div>
<div id="OneTimePaymentFormDiv">
...
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("input[name='PaymentTypeRadio'").click(function(){
  var radioValue = $("input[name='PaymentTypeRadio']:checked").val();
  switch (radioValue) {
    case "onetime":
      $('#PreauthDiv').hide();
      $('#OneTimePaymentFormDiv').show();
      break;
    case "preauth":
      $('#PreauthDiv').show();
      $('#OneTimePaymentFormDiv').hide();
      break;
    }
});
```

Maybe something to do with 2 inputs with the same name? I'm really not sure what else to try.

Comment: did you try the change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket in your selector function, which ends up in this error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name='PaymentTypeRadio'`

Change it to `$("input[name='PaymentTypeRadio']").click(function(){...}`

and it should work.

Comment: Oh man, thank you. I looked at it so many times and didn't notice. And of course every other browser out there was like oh ya, I know what you meant, no problem, even Chrome on iOS had no problem, and even Safari on MacOS, no problem. But Safari only on iOS was like nope.

Comment: Haha true, I find Safari to be the ultimate test to put a web app through.